# how to use a pyspark when function with an or condition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to use withColumn to null out bad dates in a column in a dataframe,  I'm using a when() function to make the update.  I have two conditions for "bad" dates.  dates before jan 1900 or dates in the future. My current code looks like this:

```
d = datetime.datetime.today()
df_out = df.withColumn(my_column, when(col(my_column) < '1900-01-01' | col(my_column) > '2019-12-09 17:01:37.774418', lit(None)).otherwise(col(my_column)))
```

I think my problem is that it doesn't like the or operator "|" .   From what I have seen on google "|" is what i should use.  I have tried "or" as well.   Can anyone advise on what i'm doing wrong here.

here is the stack trace.

````
df_out = df.withColumn(c, when(col(c) < '1900-01-01' | col(c) > '2019-12-09 17:01:37.774418', lit(None)).otherwise(col(c)))
  File "C:\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\column.py", line 115, in _
    njc = getattr(self._jc, name)(jc)
  File "C:\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "C:\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 332, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o48.or. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method or([class java.lang.String]) does not exist```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a problem of priority of operators. The error is telling you that `pyspark` cannot apply `OR` to a string. More specifically, it is trying to compute `'1900-01-01' | col(c)` and tells you that it does not know how to do it. You simply need to parenthesize the expression.

```py
df_out = df.withColumn(my_column, when((col(my_column) < '1900-01-01') | (col(my_column) > '2019-12-09 17:01:37.774418'), lit(None)).otherwise(col(my_column)))
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a matter of operator precedence. The boolean OR operator `or` has lower precedence than the comparison operators so

```
col(my_column) < 'X' or col(my_column) > 'Y'
```

reads as

```
(col(my_column) < 'X') or (col(my_column) > 'Y')
```

But the bitwise OR operator `|` has higher precedence than the comparison operators and

```
col(my_column) < 'X' | col(my_column) > 'Y'
```

actually reads as

```
col(my_column) < ('X' | col(my_column)) > 'Y'
```

Despite `|` being redefined on the `Column` type to have the same effect as the `or` operator, its precedence does not change, so you need to manually parenthesise each subexpression.