# Filter to new DF if column Exists in current DF

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a flat file which has 998 column in it. I need to check if 998 column is present and 999 column is not present and then put those data in a new DF.

I had tried the following:

Created a function `has_column(df, columnName)` which returns `True` or `False`. Tested this function:

```
print(has_column(df,'_998')) - True
print(has_column(df,'_999')) - False
```

In my Filter I am trying the following:

```
validRecordsDF=df.filter((has_column(df,'_996') == True & has_column(df,'_997') == False)).collect()
```

Here it fails in Spark - `TypeError: condition should be string or Column`

I need this to filter only the Records which has 998 columns.

If there is any other approach in Spark, please do let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use a pyspark when function with an or condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59270132/how-to-use-a-pyspark-when-function-with-an-or-condition) It is a matter of operator precedence - `&` has higher precedence than `==`. Parenthesise each sub-expression.

Comment: @HristoIliev - I will check the same. After reading the issue , i thought it is not matching the issue. Let me try and let you know.

Comment: I have tried to put the expressions under parenthesis ,

validRecordsDF=df.filter(( (has_column(df,'_996') == True) & (has_column(df,'_997') == False) )).collect()

But still i get the same Error

TypeError: condition should be string or Column

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Your `has_column()` function returns literally true of false. You cannot use it in the filter expression. You need to return a column expression that then evaluates to true of false for each row in the dataset. Update your question and show the code for the `has_column()` function.

Comment: @HristoIliev - Following the Has_column() function

def has_column(df, col):
    try:
        df[col]
        return True
    except AnalysisException:
        return False

Comment: If that is your check, then using `filter()` is meaningless. The dataset either has column `_996` or not. This is not a row-wise property - either all rows have column `_996` or none of them has it.

Comment: @HristoIliev - Yes i was checking that now. I was able to see that even though a particular row is not having column _996 , but still the overall DF column number is _996.
Can you let me know if there is any other approach for the same to filter out records which do not have that particular _996 ?

Comment: It is not possible for a row not to have a certain column that the dataset has. It may be empty, or NULL, but not missing.

Comment: @HristoIliev - Yes , but how to identify those records and filter. Because when we recieve the file the last column can be having Null in it.

Comment: That's a different problem than the one described in the question. Use `df.filter(df['_996'].isNotNull() & df['_997'].isNotNull())` in that case.

Comment: @HristoIliev : Thanks for the info.
I had just tried the same with a sample data. 
i got the followiing error when trying to collect.

Input row doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema. 5 fields are required while 4 values are provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to do a File processing as it was taking much time in Python as we have 996 column with close to 1M records in each file, so decided it to move it to spark and process the job pretty faster,

In DF if a column is null, when collect() is called it throws an error for missing fields 5 fields are required while 4 values are provided.

Instead, i tried the operations to keep in RDD itself and split the good and bad records like the following example,
correctColumnRDD=splitDataRDD.filter(lambda z: len(z) == 5)
incorrectColumnRDD=splitDataRDD.filter(lambda z: len(z) != 5)

Which i am then using for further processing.

Thanks @hristolliev for helping me.

Regards & Thanks all.